# Child view height is zero inside ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to have a transparent view behind the LinearLayout which can consume click events, but only those events that were not consumed by LinearLayout children, so I use the following layout xml for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/test_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                    ....
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

The problem (**when content is long enough to not fit in a screen**):

on android 2.3 view (id="test_view") has a zero height but on android 4.2 it has height as big as its parent FrameLayout.

Tried to add dynamically this view through addView in code but not working, replaced FrameLayout with RelativeLayout - the same problem.

It works only with concrete height value (for example, 20dp), but I want this view to be as big as its parent. Please, help to resolve this problem.

Comment: Why don't you remove the `<LinearLayout> <LinearLayout/>` and see how it will behave (just for the test)?

Comment: This problem arises when content (in this case LinearLayout) doesn't fit in a screen, so if i remove it - all works fine.

Comment: Do you mean to tell me that you're using different screen sizes (for different Androids obviously) with different densities and you expect each of them to visualize the content of the LinearLayout the same way?

Comment: LinearLayout is displayed the same way on different android-s. I just want my view (with id="test_view") would have a correct height (match_parent), because there is a special logic with it in code.

Comment: Then I guess that you'll have to change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` of the `FrameLayout` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` if this is applicable for your needs.

Comment: Doesn't help..The bottomline of all of this is to have a view behind the LinearLayout which can consume click events, but only those events that were not consumed by LinearLayout children, that is why I need the view and LinearLayout have the same height and width and be as big as their parent.

Comment: If those layouts overlap each other, then the topmost visible one will always receive the click events. You can change the visibility of those two, so that the correct one will receive those, but you also have to set `android:id` to the LinearLayout. Anyway, what is the difference if the clicks are received from the `View` or from the `LinearLayout` ?

Comment: I want to handle user clicks on a screen in any point except those wich are inside some LinearLayout children views (something similar to ActionBarOverlayLayout (ex. Gallery picture view) but slightly different and simpler). LinearLayout contains some text, clickable buttons and clickable images. If click is consumed by any clickable LinearLayout child I just start a corresponding activity, if not, when it will be consumed by test_view and i'll show a specific overlay panel.

Comment: If you don't fill the View "test_view" with anything, then it will only contain what's inside the LinearView. I don't think that you'll have a problem with that. Anyway, you can put `android:onClick="testViewClicked"` to handle the click events on the other on the View. I f you want to have a blank space, which the user can click, you have to fill it with something or to hardcode the height, as you did, otherwise it will be 1px of height I think.

Comment: But if the View "test_view" has zero height (as on android 2.3) it can't consume any touch events. On android 4.2 this View without any children has correct height...Replacing tag <View> with <FrameLayout>, <RelativeLayout> etc. also doesn't help...

Comment: If I got this correctly you need something like a `fragment` in you `RelativeLayout`, but since this is supported from API 11 (Android 3.0) and above this isn't the solution. The final result should look like a buffer area (some unused space) then the `LinearView` with the Buttons etc. This requires a general solution, because for some Android APIs the height of the View is zero and for others it isn't does not guarantee it will be working for newer Androids than 4.2. You may want to consider filling the View with some contents and make them invisible.That way they will still occupy the space.